# Writing inline assembly in a separate .S file

Tags: c, eclipse, assembly, arm, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to separate my assembly code from my C code because of a suggestion on another question but I'm getting this error:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -mfpu=neon -o src/ASM.o ../src/ASM.c 
In file included from ../src/ASM.c:1:0:
../src/asm.S:1:12: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘:’ token
 mul64x64asm:
      ^
```

I tried putting a semicolon in a bunch of places but it didn't solve my problem any help is appreciated even if it's not related to this problem.
Here are my ASM.c and asm.S files:

ASM.c

```
#include "asm.S"

int main(void) {
    extern  void mul64x64asm();
    mul64x64asm();
    return 1;

}
```

asm.S

```
mul64x64asm:
      MOVW R0,0x12f4
      MOVT R0,0x5678
```

UPDATE:
I tried the suggested answers and ended up with this

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-as -g --gstabs -o src/asm.o ../src/asm.S 
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -mfpu=neon -o src/ASM.o ../src/ASM.c 
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o ASM src/ASM.o src/asm.o ../src/asm.S 
src/ASM.o: In function `main':
/home/yunus/eclipse-workspace/ASM/Debug/../src/ASM.c:4: undefined reference to `mul64x64asm'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think eclipse is compiling both asm.S and ASM.c into objects and linking them here.

UPDATE 2:
So I followed @fuz 's instructions and changed my asm.S file a bit 
asm.S

```
.globl mul64x64asm
mul64x64asm:
          MOVW R0,0x12f4
          MOVT R0,0x5678
```

I wanted to get this working with as little code as possible so I removed the .size symbol.

```
../src/asm.S:2: Error: unrecognised symbol type ""
```

removed the type symbol and I'm now getting this error:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-as -g --gstabs -o src/asm.o ../src/asm.S 
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o ASM src/ASM.o src/asm.o ../src/asm.S 
/tmp/ccYM9smZ.o: In function `mul64x64asm':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `mul64x64asm'
src/asm.o:../src/asm.S:3: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Removed my asm.S file from the linker configuration in eclipse so it doesn't get linked in this line:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o ASM src/ASM.o src/asm.o ../src/asm.S
```

And finally got it working. Thanks to everyone for their answers/comments.

FINAL UPDATE: In order to debug my code in eclipse I had to include some more lines in the asm.S file here is the final version I ended up with:

```
.text
.globl mul64x64asm
.type mul64x64asm,%function 
mul64x64asm:
           mov r0, #2
           mov r1, #3
           bx lr
           .size mul64x64asm,.-mul64x64asm
```

Comment: Instead of `#include`ing your assembly code you should assemble it separately and link the resulting object file into your final binary. What you should include is a header that declares the global symbols in your assembly code.

Comment: Can't you link them together?

Comment: I also tried linking them together without include but I end up with an undefined reference error @klutt

Comment: In your previous question you weren't instructed to `include` a separate asm file like this. The person who commented suggested you create a separate asm file - the implication is that you assemble it as an object file and then link to it.

Comment: @YunusGulcu You get an undefined reference error because you forgot to set `mul64x64asm` to be a global symbol. Refer to the assembler manual for how to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there.  To add a function written in assembly to your program, place it in a separate file as you already did.

Make sure to mark all symbols you want to use elsewhere in your program as global so the linker considers them while linking:

```
    .globl mul64x64asm
    .type mul64x64asm,%function
mul64x64asm:
    MOVW R0,0x12f4
    MOVT R0,0x5678
    bx lr                        @ don't forget to return instead of fallthrough
    .size mul64x64asm,.-mul64x64asm
```

The `.globl` directive adjusts the symbol visibility to *global.* The `.type` directive marks the symbol type as *function,* this is important when you use dynamic linking.  The `.size` directive sets the symbol size of `mul64x64asm` to the difference between here (`.`) and the beginning of the function.  This is useful for debugging but can be omitted if you are too lazy.

On non-ARM, `.type mul64x64asm,@function` would be used, but `@` is the comment character on ARM so gas uses `%` instead.

Now assemble this and link it into your program like any other object file.

Answer (score 2):

The preporocessor and the `#include` directive is kind of misguided. It will quite literally paste the code from the included file into the file doing the `#include`.

After preprocessing, your code will look something like

```
mul64x64asm:
      MOVW R0,0x12f4
      MOVT R0,0x5678

int main(void) {
    extern  void mul64x64asm();
    mul64x64asm();
    return 1;

}
```

That is certainly not valid C code.

If you want to do inline-assembly you have to do it in a way that the compiler understands. [Find the documentation for your version of GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/), and read more about it.

Another and possibly better choice is to build the `asm.S` source file into an object file with an assembler. Then link your main program with this object file to create the executable program.

Answer (score 2):

You should make an `.o` from your assembly. Then you compile your c code with something like:

```
gcc main.c asm.o
```